# How can I do a term search and ignore case?

Tags: java, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using the Java API to create searches, and noticed through testing that my searches vary by upper and lower case in my search terms. I figure there must be a simple solution, but I have yet to find it in the MarkLogic Java API documentation.

My query looks a bit like this:

```
StructuredQueryBuilder queryBuilder = queryManager.newStructuredQueryBuilder();
StructuredQueryDefinition queryDef = queryBuilder.and(
    queryBuilder.term(term),
    queryBuilder.value(
        queryBuilder.elementAttribute(
            queryBuilder.element(new QName(my-namespace,"document") ),
            queryBuilder.attribute("locale")
        ),
        language)
);
```

I tried messing around with the term() method, but it doesn't really have a lot to it. Or is this related to a DB setting I need to flip rather than something that goes on the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `queryBuilder.term()` corresponds to the underlying [cts:word-query](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:word-query) function, which has this note in its documentation:

> If neither "case-sensitive" nor "case-insensitive" is present, $text is used to determine case sensitivity. If $text contains no uppercase, it specifies "case-insensitive". If $text contains uppercase, it specifies "case-sensitive".

Doesn't look like you can pass options into `term()`, but the case of the terms you pass it likely affect how the query is interpreted.

Comment: OK cool. So I suppose converting the search term to lower care before passing it in would achieve what I want then. Thanks!

Comment: Please note that you can install named search options (including term options http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_31590 ) on the server and reference it in the call to newStructuredQueryBuilder(optionsName) http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_52113